# IOptonsMonitor.OnChange and async listener in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a class registered as a singleton. In the constructor of this class, I subscribe to IOptonsMonitor.OnChange:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> myOptionsMonitor)
    {
        myOptionsMonitor.OnChange(async options => await SomeWork());
    }

    public async Task SomeWork()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
}
```

In this case SomeWork task will actually "Fire and Forgot" which is probably wrong. Another approach is to run SomeWork synchronously:

```
myOptionsMonitor.OnChange(options => SomeWork().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

But in this case, OnChange will be blocked for a time of SomeWork execution.

Which approach will be more correct?

Comment: What does `SomeWork` actually do? If it can be fire and forget then there is nothing wrong to use it as fire and forget.

Comment: It makes some external requests using IHttpClient

Comment: Making external calls does not mean it can't be fire and forget. If you need to block other listeners until the calls are completed, then you can't do fire forget. Otherwise, if the calls are on their own, won't affect other listeners, then you can do fire forget.

Comment: This also applies to the same listener. Fire forget also means `SomeWork` could be triggered again while another `SomeWork` is in progress.